# htaccess not working under wamp server on windows 7

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wamp

I know there are several questions on this topic and I've read them but none of them seem to help. Some common suggestions:

- did you enable the rewrite_module

Yes, I did and it's checked when I look at the apache modules list that you can pop up from the wamp server icon.

- did you add "AllowOverride All" to one of the  specifications.

I did. There are more than one and I've tried several. I don't know which directory to add it to. Yes, I have added it to the directory specification for the directory which is the root of the app and holds the .htaccess file.

As far as I can tell the .htaccess file is never even looked at. The URL which is supposed to be rewritten to something that exists returns a 404 typically, except for occasionally when I manage to make the whole app refuse permissions to my browser (403)

Some possible complications: I'm using a virtual host. It is at c:/wamp/vhosts/myapp instead of c:\wamp\www\myapp. My virtual hosts definition is in C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf instead of httpd.conf. Also I've configured my app to also run python however I'm not using it yet.

It's a fresh install from Friday. I know it's possible because I've done it before. I just have no idea which magic incantation I got wrong this time.

Comment: The best test I have found for if your .htaccess is being hit is to put some gibberish in it and see if you get a 500 response. Do you?

Comment: That's a great tip. Doing that I find that my .htaccess is indeed getting hit. I can not try to figure out why what I have there is not effective.

Thank!

Comment: No problem, nothing more frustrating than trying everything and seeing absolutely no effect. The gibberish followed by the 500 is a little cathartic too :P

Comment: What are you testing? Can you put the .htaccess content?